# Entity Framework: Adding items to a collection wont persist in database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I created a project with a model first approach, in my model I declared a many to many relationship between the entities, `Musician` and `Session` (representing some kind of rehearsal or performance). As expected, this generated a pivot table in my database to handle the relationship, but no C# model class for the intermediate table. So, on my `Session` object I have a collection of `Musicians` declared as an `ICollection`:

```
public virtual ICollection<Musician> Musicians { get; set; }
```

Which is initialised as a `HashSet` in the `Session` constructor:

```
public Session()
{
    this.Musicians = new HashSet<Musician>();
}
```

Now, somewhere else in my solution (in an MVC controller, if it matters), I want to assign an existing `Musician` to a given `Session`, so I have this code:

```
Musician musician = db.Musicians.First(m => m.Id == selectedMusician);
session.Musicians.Add(musician);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Just after `session.Musicians.Add(musician)` is called, I've inspected that the musician has been added to the collection, but calling `db.SaveChanges` doesn't seem to persist the change to the database.

By the way, db is my repository containing all my models, for example, this code successfully adds a new `Session` to the database:

```
db.Sessions.Add(session);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If somebody could point me in the right direction on how to add an object to a collection in this circumstance that would be a great help.

Cheers

EDIT: Turns out the problem had nothing to do with the fact that it was a collection. Like I mentioned in my post, I was trying to make the changes/saving from a controller class in an ASP MVC project. The session object was being passed in from the view, but I discovered any changes I made to this object wouldn't persist in the database (doh, silly me, should of checked this straight away). Looks like the object passed in by the view was just a copy as it wasn't coming directly from the context (in this case, my db object).
To fix it, I just queried the context for a `Session` object with the same Id in order to have access to the object that my changes would actually persist.

Comment: so is Musicians a table defined in db?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code in your question, it should work. You don't get any exceptions?

Comment: @Wim No exceptions, db.SaveChanges() gets called, I check the database and there is no SessionMusician entry (SessionMusician is the table for a Session-Musician relationship, I can add entries to it manually and my collections correctly recognize the relationship)

Comment: You don't show how did you get session in your example. If it is not attached to context there will be no change saved to database.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka you were right, thank you! :)
The session I had was being returned by a view in my MVC application, I just queried the context (the db object) for a session with the same ID, made my changes to that object, called SaveChanges and it worked.